# routerLink syntax when targeting multiple router-outlets (primary + aux)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Does anyone know why link #1 and #2 work but link #3 doesn't?

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/contact']">Contact Solo</a> |
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { aux: 'aside' }}]">Aux Solo</a> |
<a [routerLink]="['/contact', { outlets: { aux: 'aside' }}]">Contact + Aux</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="aux"></router-outlet>
```

In other words: I can activate the primary route individually (link #1), I can activate the auxiliary route individually (link #2), but **I can't activate the primary route AND the auxiliary route simultaneously** (link #3). Link #3 only activates the primary route but triggers no error in the console.

Interestingly, *clicking link #1 then link #2* produces what I want (primary route AND auxiliary activated) with a path of `contact(aux:aside)` whereas link #3 has a path of `contact/(aux:aside)` (notice the `/`).

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/WqTRjux7muHjalIL3rsL?p=preview

Route declaration:

```ts
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'contact',
    component: ContactComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'aside',
    component: PopupComponent,
    outlet: 'aux'
  }
];
```

I've tried multiple combinations and syntaxes to no avail.

Comment: I think since `path: 'contact'` have a default `pathMatch: prefix`, whenever the url sees the `contact`, it discards the `outlet` if you don't "confuse" the url (clicking on 2 then 1)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried adding `pathMatch: "full"` to the `contact` route but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Hi, how to pass two parameters for primary outlet to get this: URL/param1:value/param2:value

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try below,

```
 <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { primary: 'contact', aux: 'aside' }}]">Contact + Aux</a>
```

updated [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/gDC1IMZQAUVAZkmcbpFf?p=preview)!!

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hi, how to pass two parameters for primary outlet to get this: URL/param1:value/param2:value