# Navigating a main outlet and named outlets in one routerLink

Tags: angular, angular-router

Is it possible to navigate both the main outlet and named outlets within the same routerLink?  I've tried different combinations and nothing seems to work.

app.routing.ts

```
{ 
  path: 'test', 
  component: RedComponent,
},
{
  path:'test',
  component: RedComponent,
  outlet: 'header1'
},
{
  path:'test',
  component: RedComponent,
  outlet: 'header2'
},
```

app.component.html

```
<div>
Header:
  <router-outlet name="header1"></router-outlet>
</div>
<div>
Header2:
  <router-outlet name="header2"></router-outlet>
</div>
<div>
Main:
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

This will route the named outlets, but how do you navigate the main outlet as well?

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { header1: ['test'], header2: ['test'] } }]">Outlet Nav</a>
```

This stackblitz sets it up nicely.  If you click `Main outlet nav` you will see the main square turn red. You can click the `Outlet nav` and the named outlets change. How can you turn both routes on at the same time?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-outlets

Comment: The link doesn't work

Comment: @Andrey fixed!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554091/routerlink-syntax-when-targeting-multiple-router-outlets-primary-aux        `[routerLink]="[{ outlets: { primary: ['test'], header1: ['test'], header2: ['test'] } }]"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [routerLink syntax when targeting multiple router-outlets (primary + aux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554091/routerlink-syntax-when-targeting-multiple-router-outlets-primary-aux)