# Make router link active on two different routes

Tags: angular

In angular how can I make routerlink `active` on two different routes. i.e.

```
<li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
```

will have the style `active` when "dashboard" is the route. Is there a way to have the same link be styled active when at a different url e.g. "home" as well?

Comment: I guess I could use ngClass and take a snapshot of the url in the component and conditionally apply the class 'active' if the snapshot contains the links I'm interested in.

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554091/routerlink-syntax-when-targeting-multiple-router-outlets-primary-aux

Comment: Not really the same thing. I'm not looking to open both components. Just have the router link be styled as active on multiple routes.

Comment: So the styling is dependent on 2 routes, but the routerlink only has 1 redirect?

Comment: @JonasPraem correct I came up with a solution in my answer below, I thought there might be a more "built-in" solution but probably not.

Answer (score 2):

So I found a solution for anyone who wants to do the same thing. I can't guarantee it's the most efficient solution. I check the url path using a Router like so:

```
isDashboard: boolean;
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
            if(event.url.includes('home')) {
                this.isDashboard = true;
            }
            else this.isDashboard = false;
        });
}
```

then on the link I add `[class.active]="isDashboard"` and just leaving the properties like they were on the link in my question (you could add any links you like here). Gets the job done but I was looking for a less intense solution, preferably that could be implemented only in the DOM.