# Second level navigation in Angular

Tags: angular, routes

I am using Angular 10 and I have a problem with routing - I have two menus, navigation on the top and side menu and I would like to implement sth like 2nd level routing.
here are my routing rules:

```js
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent },
  { path: 'admin/rank1', component: Rank1Component, outlet: "rank" },
  { path: 'admin/rank2', component: Rank2Component, outlet: "rank" },     
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
])
```

this is my main component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: `<p>
    <a [routerLink]="['/home']">HOME</a> | 
    <a [routerLink]="['/admin']">ADMIN</a> 
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </p>`
})

export class AppComponent {}
```

this is my `AdminComponent`:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: `<p>
       <a [routerLink]="['/admin(rank:rank1)']">RANK1</a> | 
       <a [routerLink]="['/admin(rank:rank2)']">RANK2</a> 
       <router-outlet name="rank"></router-outlet>
  </p>`
})

export class AdminComponent {}
```

Everything is fine except routing for AdminComponent - the second level navigation inside AdminComponent does not work
Could you please help?

Comment: Maybe this is the answer you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554091/routerlink-syntax-when-targeting-multiple-router-outlets-primary-aux

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with routing level. You provide two `<router-outlet>`-s, but you have no children for route `admin`. Your additional routes will not be rendered, as only one component can be rendered by one `router-outlet`.

Proposal made by @Morty was perfectly valid and It's only way you can deal now in such structure. Every `<router-outlet>` is dedicated for `child` routes of their parent. You declared two outlets but only one level or f routing, thus only one, most matching component will be rendered instead of two.

And, just providing `name` attribute is not enough to force children to be rendered.

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can try to use Children routes:

```
  {
    path: 'home', component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'admin', component: AdminpanelComponent
    children: [{
      path: 'rank1', component: AllpostsComponent
    }, {
      path: 'rank2', component: AllroomsComponent
    }
    ]
  }'
```

Than you can route to your pages like that:

```
<button routerLink="admin">Go to admin Page</button>
```

```
<button routerLink="rank1">Go to Ranks 1 under Admin Route</button>
```

the url will look like this:
localhost:4200/admin/ranks1

Comment: It is not I would like to achieve. In admin component I have second level nagivation. Please have a look at my post